# greek symbol for axis label in R zoo plot

Tags: r, zoo

I am trying to plot a zoo series with a Greek symbol as the axis label.

Here is the code:

```
mu_val <- 1
plot(1:10,101:110,main=bquote(mu~'='~.(mu_val)))  ## works fine
plot(1:10,101:110,ylab=bquote(mu~'='~.(mu_val)))  ## works fine
plot(zoo(101:110,1:10),main=bquote(mu~'='~.(mu_val)))  ## works fine
plot(zoo(101:110,1:10),ylab=bquote(mu~'='~.(mu_val)))  ## gives error
## Error in title(...) : invalid mathematical annotation
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me, because even `plot(zoo(101:110,1:10),xlab=bquote(mu~'='~.(mu_val)))` works

Comment: You should  contact the package maintainer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a bug to me, because as I said in comments, even

`plot(zoo(101:110,1:10),xlab=bquote(mu~'='~.(mu_val)))`

works. I think you should report it to the `zoo` package maintainers

The only way I could make it work is using `title`

```
plot(zoo(101:110,1:10),ylab="")
title(ylab = bquote(mu~'='~.(mu_val)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could try

`plot(zoo(101:110,1:10),ylab=expression(paste(mu,"=1")))`

if you do traceback(), you can see that it the issue is in `title` function  from help `?title`

```
They must be of type character or expression. In the latter case, quite a bit of mathematical
notation is available such as sub- and superscripts, greek letters, fractions, etc: see plotmath
```

[image]

Comment: The thing is I want "=1" to be a variable set at run time.